# Warning: Cannot update a component (`Home`) while rendering a different component (`Posts`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Posts`,

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Problem: when i click on the button

```
<button
 onClick={() => {
     navigate('/posts');
     setResponse(e.id);
      }}
 >
```

I get this error: `Warning: Cannot update a component (`Home`) while rendering...`

I think problem only in this line

```
navigate('/posts');
```

because if I delete it, error disappears

full code under without import

App.js

```
function App() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState({});
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home setResponse={setResponse} />} />
        <Route exact path="/posts" element={<Posts response={response} />} />
        <Route exact path="*" />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.js

```
function Home({ setResponse }) {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const state = useSelector((state) => state);
  console.log(state);
  if (state.user.isLoading) {
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  }

  const toggleModal = () => {
    setModal(!modal);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={(e) => dispatch(fetchUsers())}>Fetch users</button>
      {state.user.data &&
        state.user.data.map((e) => (
          <div key={e.id}>
            <li key={e.name}>{e.name}</li>
            <button
              key={e.id + 10}
              onClick={() => {
                navigate('/posts');
                setResponse(e.id);
              }}
              className="btn"
            >
              Posts
            </button>
            <button onClick={toggleModal} key={e.id + 100} className="bnt">
              Albums
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}

      <Albums modal={modal} setModal={setModal} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Posts.js

```
function Posts({ response }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const state = useSelector((state) => state);
  console.log(state);
  if (state.post.isLoading) {
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  }
  if (!state.post.data) {
    dispatch(fetchPosts());
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      Posts
      {state.post.data &&
        state.post.data
          .filter((e) => e.userId === response)
          .map((e) => (
            <div key={e.userId.toString() + e.id.toString()}>
              <li key={e.id}>{e.title}</li>
            </div>
          ))}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          navigate('/');
        }}
      >
        List of users
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Posts;
```

I tried to use `useEffect()`, but it doesn't work in my case

```
<button
 onClick={() => {useEffect(()=>{
     navigate('/posts');
     setResponse(e.id);},[])
 }}
 >
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're navigating away to another page, you shouldn't be updating the state as you're navigating (which you're doing by calling `setResponse` after `navigate`).

To fix this error, you'd have to call `navigate()` after React finishes updating the `response` variable, which you can do by using a `useEffect` call at the top-level of your `Home` component:

```
// you should also pass the value of response to the Home component so it knows when it's been changed
function Home({ setResponse, response }) {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const state = useSelector((state) => state);
  console.log(state);

  useEffect(() => {
    // This if statement checks if response === {}, which is a bit awkward; you should instead initialize your response state to a value like `null`
    if (typeof response === 'object' && Object.keys(response).length === 0) {
      return
    }
    navigate('/posts')
  }, [response])

  if (state.user.isLoading) {
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  }

  const toggleModal = () => {
    setModal(!modal);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={(e) => dispatch(fetchUsers())}>Fetch users</button>
      {state.user.data &&
        state.user.data.map((e) => (
          <div key={e.id}>
            <li key={e.name}>{e.name}</li>
            <button
              key={e.id + 10}
              onClick={() => {
                // navigate('/posts');
                setResponse(e.id);
              }}
              className="btn"
            >
              Posts
            </button>
            <button onClick={toggleModal} key={e.id + 100} className="bnt">
              Albums
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}

      <Albums modal={modal} setModal={setModal} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: I made like you wrote, and it show me the same error. Maybe you think that my variable "response" is a object, but in my case it just a "number"(id number that i got from a button).

Comment: and right now i see that `<button onClick={() => {navigate('/');} ` doesn't  work, but before using `useEffect` she worked

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. Have you seen this one?

When passing a callback using dispatch to a child component, you may sometimes want to memoize it with useCallback. If the child component is trying to optimize render behavior using React.memo() or similar, this avoids unnecessary rendering of child components due to the changed callback reference.

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

export const CounterComponent = ({ value }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const incrementCounter = useCallback(
    () => dispatch({ type: 'increment-counter' }),
    [dispatch]
  )

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{value}</span>
      <MyIncrementButton onIncrement={incrementCounter} />
    </div>
  )
}

export const MyIncrementButton = React.memo(({ onIncrement }) => (
  <button onClick={onIncrement}>Increment counter</button>
))
```

[Here is a link to read more, I use an Anonymous function in the onClick button and it works](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks)